# Residue of the function $\frac{\sin (2z)-2z}{(1-\cos z)^2}$ for $z_0=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving, laurent-series

I have this function

> $$\frac{\sin (2z)-2z}{(1-\cos z)^2}$$

I want to find its residue around $z_0=0$, however I've been battling it for hours but I get nowhere. I've tried finding its Laurent series, but it seemed too complicated so I thought the way to go was to use the fact that $0$ is a pole of order $2$, and use the formula 
$$\frac1{1!}\lim_{z\to0}\frac d{dz}\left[z^2\left(\frac{\sin (2z)-2z}{(1-\cos z)^2}\right)\right]$$
Maybe I'm using wrong ways to do this, maybe I'm just too sick of this function, but it seems that this is even worse, I get nowhere... I already run this in [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit&a=*C.limit-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=derivative%20%28x%5E2%28%28sin%282x%29-2x%29/%281-cos%20x%29%5E2%29%29&f=Limit.limitfunction_derivative%20%28x%5E2%28%28sin%282x%29-2x%29/%281-cos%20x%29%5E2%29%29&f3=0&f=Limit.limit%5Cu005f0&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Limit.limitvariable--.**Limit.direction--.**Limit.limitvariable2-.*Limit.limit2-.*Limit.direction2---.*--) and it appears that the limit exists.

Is there another way to find this residue? Am I even doing things right?

*I really should stop obsessing with this, but once you get caught is difficult to stop.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so I thought the way to go was to use the fact that $0$ is a pole of order $2$,

It isn't. It's a simple pole,

$$\sin (2z) - 2z = - \frac{(2z)^3}{3!} + O(z^5),$$

and

$$(1-\cos z)^2 = \left(\frac{z^2}{2!} + O(z^4)\right)^2 = \frac{z^4}{4} + O(z^6).$$

I leave it to you to finish the computation of the residue.

Comment: Oh my... I can not belive I didn't notice before...